# Read parquet with filter on datetimeindex

Tags: python, filter, parquet

I'm reading a parquet file with symbol and Datetime as the multiindex like so

```
        Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
Symbol  Datetime                        
A   2022-03-21 07:00:00-04:00   139.12  139.12  139.12  139.12  139.12  0
2022-03-21 08:00:00-04:00   139.61  139.61  139.61  139.61  139.61  0
2022-03-21 09:30:00-04:00   137.63  138.57  137.63  138.26  138.26  27491
2022-03-21 09:33:00-04:00   139.01  139.12  138.89  138.89  138.89  12302
2022-03-21 09:34:00-04:00   138.93  139.31  138.93  139.31  139.31  2929
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

I'm trying to return only the regular market hour (from 9:30 AM to 4pm), so I tried

```
dfBig = pd.read_parquet('AAPL.parquet', filters=[('Symbol','=', 'A'), (pd.to_datetime(dfBig['Datetime']).hour, '=', '09')])
```

It returns KeyError: 'Datetime'

If I tried

```
dfBig = pd.read_parquet('AAPL.parquet', filters=[('Symbol','=', 'A'), (pd.to_datetime('Datetime').hour, '=', '09')])
```

Unknown string format: Datetime

I could store the datetime as a regular string if that helps.

Any ideas I could resolve the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, instead of fighting this, I just write the parquet file as

Symbol, Date, time as multiIndex

so a simple > < or = will do the trick

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).